# Wordpress Pre Fill content in Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an admin plugin that has a list of articles in it with a button "Add to Posts" along side. On the click of that button, I want to redirect to "/wp-admin/post-new.php" with the form pre filled.

I can set the title in the url like `wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=post&post_title=My Titlle`. But, how can I pre fill the content?

I read some articles like [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/auto-populate-posts), but its not what I am looking for.

Also, the content is going to be different each time, so I don't want to set it as default.

What I am doing right now :

My jQuery on button click :

```
function add_to_post(id) {

    var data = {
        'action'    : 'add_to_post',
        'id'    : id
    };

    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : ajaxurl,
        data    : data
    })
    .done(function(){

        var title   = $(document.getElementById('title_'+id)).text(); 
        var link    = host+"/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=post&post_title="+title;
        window.open(link,"_blank");
    })
    ;
}
```

My Plugin code for Action

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_to_post','add_to_post_callback');

function add_to_post_callback() {

    add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content', 10 , 2 );

    wp_die();
}

function my_editor_content( $content ) {

    $content = "This is some custom content I'm adding to the post editor because I hate re-typing it.";

    return $content;
}
```

But when I click on "Add to post" button, the content is still empty 
I would appreciate any help.

Aman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing :

in jQuery :

```
function add_to_post(feed_id) {

    var title   = $(document.getElementById('title_'+feed_id)).text(); 
    var content = $(document.getElementById('summary_'+feed_id)).text(); 
    var link    = host+"/wp-admin/post-new.php";

    var data = {
        'post_title'    : title,
        'pre_content'   : content,
        'post_type'     : 'post'
    };

    $.extend({
        redirectPost: function(location, args) {
            var form = '';
            $.each( args, function( key, value ) {
                form += '<input type="hidden" name="'+key+'" value="'+value+'">';
            });
            $('<form target = "_blank" action="'+location+'" method="POST">'+form+'</form>').appendTo('body').submit();
        }
    });
    // sending content as post because Get request has character limit of 2048. Just taking no chances.
    $.redirectPost(link,data);
}
```

In PHP

```
//To add content to your post.
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content', 10 , 2 );

function my_editor_content( $content , $post ) {

    if(isset($_POST['pre_content'])) {
        $content = $_POST['pre_content'];
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has a filter for default content:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'set_default_content', 10, 2 );
function set_default_content( $content, $post ) {
    $content = ...your content...;
    return $content;
}
```

You can just use a variable for the content and change it whenever you like.

Comment: Hey bobdye, I tried doing what you said - but the content still comes out empty. I made edits to my question to add what I have done. If you can point me to the issue :) .. thanks

Comment: I don't know whether you can add a filter in an Ajax handler or not. Usually filters inside plugins are added in the main plugin file or in an 'init' action handler. What exactly are you trying to do with the Ajax call, since you never do anything with the `data` returned?